# adding blank cells in Excel results in error

Tags: excel

I have a problem with my formulas when a cell contains a blank.

in cell A1 I have a cell that calculates a cost
in cell B1 I add that cost to another cell to get a total

my formula in A1 is like this:
=IF([@[mycellref]]=0;0;..otherwise do this..)))

This puts zeros everywhere this is no cost to apply. OK.
However, I don't want zeros - I want a blank cell. But if I use:
=IF([@[mycellref]]=0;"";..otherwise do this..)))

my formula in B1 complains and shows an error.

Any work around I'm missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a typo in your formula. Try to paste this: =IF(A1=0;"";"OK") works for Excel 2013.

Comment: thanks, but I think it's not that (I checked). It's that my formula in B1 crashes when A1 is "". If it's a real 0, then its OK.

Comment: In this case without looking at the formula in B1 it will be hard to help.

Comment: yes, sorry - here it is:


`=IF(T_supplier_EK[@[$ ?]]=0;
((T_supplier_EK[@[other kg '#1 $]])+(T_supplier_EK[@[other kg '#1 $]]*[@[Zoll %]])+(G5));
((T_supplier_EK[@[other kg '#1 $]]/T_supplier_EK[@[Dollar Rate]])+(T_supplier_EK[@[other kg '#1 $]]*$D5/T_supplier_EK[@[Dollar Rate]])+(G5)))`


it's actually G5 that has the costs formula in it.

Comment: so we have a number of checks being done - and it all works fine. But when G5 is not a 0, but "", then it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I can't think of enything simpler than replaceing every G5 call with IF(G5<>"";G5;0) or NUMBERVALUE(G5)